# Scrolling SWT scrollBar

Tags: java, swt, scrollbar, styledtext

I have a SWT styledText area with scrollBar. I would like the scrollbar to scroll to a given index but I am experiencing some difficulties.

I tried:

```
ScrollBar vBarScroll = styledText.getVerticalBar();
vBarScroll.setSelection(textIndex);
styledText.showSelection();
```

This selects the text, which I do not want, as well as having difficulties to display. It jumops around alot too.

The other thing I tried is:

```
styledText.setTopIndex(textIndex);
```

But that doesn't work either

Comment: The units for the scroll bar are pixels not character offsets. The units for `setTopIndex` are lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**lineNoIndex** is the index of line. 
0 -> 1st line 1->Second line etc.

```
 if(lineNoIndex >= 0 && lineNoIndex < styledText.getLineCount()) {
       int offset = lineNoIndex == 0 ? 0:styledText.getOffsetAtLine(lineNoIndex) - 1;
       styledText.setCaretOffset(offset);
       styledText.setTopIndex(offset == 0 ? 0:lineNoIndex - 1);
 }
```

Comment: How do you keep the styledText from reseting the setTopIndex to 0 everytime?

Comment: Not understood, add some more explanation

Comment: everytime the .setText method is called, the .setTopIndex method gets called automatically with the value 0. I was wondering on how to stop this from happening, because it causes the text in the area to jump and look jittery

Comment: I got rid of the jumping of the text. It looks a lot smoother if you disable redraw, set the text and topIndex and then enable redraw again. If you have a better solution, I would like to hear it though

Comment: You can try calling styledText.append() if you want to append text also check other methods of StyledText these may help or post the complete code